# Can a multivariate Poisson Process be transformed to a univariate Poisson Process with an additional discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I'm currently trying to understand Poisson Processes using this material:
https://www.open.edu/openlearn/pluginfile.php/1118700/mod_resource/content/3/Modelling%20events%20in%20time_m343_1.pdf (this question is based on pages 29 and 30).

Say we have three types of events $A$, $B$, and $C$ that occur independently with rates $\lambda_A$, $\lambda_B$, and $\lambda_C$.
According to the document, this is a multivariate Poisson Process which consists of three independent univariate Poisson processes with rates $\lambda_A$, $\lambda_B$, and $\lambda_C$.

Now I'm wondering if this can also be modeled as follows (inspired by the description on the bottom of page 30):
Take a univariate Poisson Process with rate $\lambda = \lambda_A + \lambda_B + \lambda_C$.
Everytime an event occurs, we determine its type $t$ by drawing from the discrete probability distribution $T$ with the following PMF:
$$
p_T(t)=
\begin{cases}
p_A=\lambda_A/\lambda, & t=A \\
p_B=\lambda_B/\lambda, & t=B \\
p_C=\lambda_C/\lambda, & t=C \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Is this equivalent? Because I'm not sure if this hurts the independence assumption or changes something like the expected amount of events of a certain type in a certain interval.

**Edit**: If it is, would it also be equivalent if the univariate Poisson process of each type $t$ would be non-homogeneous, i.e. $\lambda_t$ would be a function of time instead of a constant?

Comment: It is equivalent for a Poisson process (I would explain it with memorylessness as a handwaving shorthand) but need not be equivalent for other similar processes

Comment: @Henry thanks for the quick reply! I just came up with another question (see edit): Would it also be equivalent if the univariate Poisson process of each type $t$ would be non-homogeneous, i.e. $λ_t$ would be a function of time instead of a constant?

Comment: If the rates are varying then the probabilities such as $\lambda_A/\lambda$ are also varying, which complicates matters, but if you know when the even took place then it is still equivalent